# Can we achieve the cascading pageblock section style in Visualforce page? let user click on (+) corresponding subsection should expand

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, home-page-component

[image: TRUST A parent Sobject, Brand(Brilique) and objective tactic and Action are grand Child Sobject]

Can we achieve the cascading pageblock section style in Visual-force page? let user click on (+) corresponding subsection should expand in fashion in image attached.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest apex:pageBlockSection elements and the section open/close behaves as you would expect.

For example, just create this page and try it:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Contact">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="One" columns="1">
            <apex:outputText value="Content"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="One Child 1" columns="1">
                <apex:outputText value="Content"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="One Child 1 Grandchild 1" columns="1">
                    <apex:outputText value="Content"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="One Child 2 Grandchild 2" columns="1">
                    <apex:outputText value="Content"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="One Child 2" columns="1">
                <apex:outputText value="Content"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Two" columns="1">
            <apex:outputText value="Content"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

But your screen shot shows something that in no way matches the styling that Visualforce provides out of the box, so if that is important you might be better off embedding some other technology in the Visualforce page such as one of these [jQuery Treeview Plugin & Tutorials with Example](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-treeview/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very rough javascript example on how to do this using jquery.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vws4d/)

Javascript

```
function collapseMeAndChildren(collapseThis){
    $collapseThisSection = $(collapseThis);
    $collapseThisParent = $collapseThisSection.parent();
    $collapseThisParent.children().each(function(){
         if(this.getAttribute('class') == 'collapseThis')
             $(this).toggle();
    });
}
```

html

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="collapseMeAndChildren(this);"><img src="http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/black-white-pearls-icons-alphanumeric/069303-black-white-pearl-icon-alphanumeric-plus-sign3-sc48.png" height="20px" width="20px" /></a> 
    Title
    <div class="collapseThis"> 
        <a href="#" onclick="collapseMeAndChildren(this);"><img src="http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/black-white-pearls-icons-alphanumeric/069303-black-white-pearl-icon-alphanumeric-plus-sign3-sc48.png" height="20px" width="20px" /></a>
        1
        <div class="collapseThis">
            <a href="#" onclick="collapseMeAndChildren(this);"><img src="http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/black-white-pearls-icons-alphanumeric/069303-black-white-pearl-icon-alphanumeric-plus-sign3-sc48.png" height="20px" width="20px" /></a>
            2
            <div class="collapseThis" onclick="collapseMeAndChildren(this);">
                3
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```